# Unix Math adds 2 0's behind my math.

Tags: shell, unix, math

I have a line of code that is producing extra 00's behind my math when I print it out to my email. I was wondering what did I do wrong here ?

```
Percentage()
{
echo "scale = 2 ;($(Value)/5)*100" | bc -l | awk '{print $0"%"}'
}
```

Istead of producing results like 29.34% , It produces 29.00%. When I add more scale it just becomes like 29.3400% instead of 29.3423%. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's `Value`? You're attempting a command substitution with it. Do you mean a variable substitution instead  (i.e., `${Value}` instead of `$(Value)`)?

Comment: I'd like to harness this bug for use in printing my paycheck ...

Comment: And what are your inputs that give you `29.00` instead of `29.34`?

Comment: That seems like a convoluted way of writing `awk "BEGIN{printf \"%.2f%%\n\", $(Value)/5*100}"`, and I'm not convinced that's optimized.  I'm assuming `Value` is a command that produces a single numeric output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Or just `$(Value)*20`. :-)

Comment: @ooga: Yes; brain wasn't in gear and there was optimization available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Value as: `1.467115`

The `scale` is applied to any (subsequent) calculation too. So, the `scale=2` from `1.467115/5` creates: `0.29` and `*100` is `29.00`.

Change the equation to:

```
Value() {
    echo "1.467115"
}
Percentage() {
    echo "scale=${1:-2};$(Value)*100/5" | bc -l | awk '{print $0"%"}'
}

Percentage
```

and produces:

```
29.34%
```

and the `Percentage 4` produces:

```
29.3423%
```

Ps: why do not use awk for calculation?